# Change Mac Address on Wireless NIC

Tags: mac-address

**Problem**

I currently use a Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6230 network adapter, and I need to spoof the mac address in order to test security on my network.

The problem is that the latest driver for this adapter does not allow spoofing.

I also purchased a Netgear N300 Wireless USB Adapter to see if I could use that to change the mac address, but no luck so far.

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how I can change my mac address?

**Additional Info :**

Windows 8 64 Bit

Dell XPS 15

8 GB Memory

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can give me!

Comment: What kind of network is that? Residential, office, ...? However, there are testing suites for Linux, and XPS 15 has full support for the Ubuntu distribution. Maybe you can try that way.

Comment: Hi Matt - sorry, but this question is offtopic here. I'll pop it over to Superuser where it will be on topic.

Comment: It's a residential network, and i'm mainly looking to do it via windows if possible.

Comment: @MattWalker, Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question ?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

So, You are on Windows Platform, Let's answer for that

## MAC Spoofing Using Tools

#### 1. [Technitium MAC Address Changer](https://technitium.com/tmac/)

- Allows complete configuration of any network adapter.
- Command line options with entire software functionality available.
- Update network card vendors list feature allows you to download latest vendor data (OUI) from IEEE.org.
- IPv6 support

**To change the Mac Address**

1. Starting MAC address changer will list all available network adapters.
2. Select the adapter you want to change the MAC address. You will get the details of your selection below.
3. In the Information tab, find the Change MAC Address frame. Enter new MAC address in the field and click Change Now! button. You may even click Random MAC Address button to fill up a randomly selected MAC address from the vendor list available.
4. To restore the original MAC address of the network adapter, select the adapter, click Restore Original button in the Change MAC Address frame.

NOTE : This tool cannot change MAC address of Microsoft Network Bridge.
Network Bridge will automatically use the original MAC address of the first NIC added into bridge with the first octet of MAC address set to 0x02.

For further help, Visit [Technitium Help](https://technitium.com/tmac/help.html)

See   [Q1  : How to Change MAC Address of a NIC ?](https://technitium.com/tmac/help.html#q1)

See [Q13 : How to Use the Command-Line Interface ?](https://technitium.com/tmac/help.html#q13)

#### 2. [System Lizard's Change MAC Address](https://lizardsystems.com/change-mac-address/)

- Shows MAC Address and Manufacturer of network adapter.
- Generates completely random MAC Address.
- Automatically activating the new MAC address after the change.

**To Change the MAC Address**

Simply Follow this [Tutorial](https://lizardsystems.com/wiki/change_mac_address/faq/tutorial_changing_mac_address_in_windows_7)

#### 3. [SMAC](https://smac.soft32.com/) ([Download Here](http://www.klcconsulting.net/smac/))

- Filters Active and Inactive Adapters.
- View , Generate and Validate MAC Address.
- 1-Click Network Adapter Restart
- IPConfig Button to show network status
- Shows MAC Change Hostory
- `The new MAC addresses you change will sustain from reboots.`

**To Change the MAC Address**

It's too easy. Just Start the tool and you'll get to know how .[See Screenshots](https://smac.soft32.com/screenshots/)

#### 4. [Portable Spoof-Me-Now](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/Network/Portable-Spoof-Me-Now.shtml)

- Very Small Size. No installation Required at all.
- JustDrop Program file and click Executable to run.
- Can be saved to any USB or Flash Drive in order to run it any PC with minimum efforts.

**To Change the MAC Address**

Just [Download](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/Network/Portable-Spoof-Me-Now.shtml) it, and Run the executable.

## MAC Spoofing Without Using Tools [See this](https://www.top-password.com/blog/change-mac-address-on-windows/)

#### 1. Configuring Network Connections

- Go to `Network and Sharing Center`
- Click `Manage Network Connections` OR `Change Adapter Settings`
- `Right-click on the adapter` and choose `Properties`.
- On the `General or Networking tab`, click the `Configure` button.
- Click on the `Advanced tab`
- Click on the `Locally Administered Address` property or the Network Address property.
- By default, the Not Present value is selected. Click on the Value radio button and enter in a new MAC address.

NOTE : The MAC address is a combination of 6 pairs of numbers and characters, i.e. 40-A2-D9-82-9F-F2. You should enter the MAC address without the dashes.

- Go to command prompt and type `IPCONFIG /ALL` to check that the MAC address has been changed.
- Now `Restart the computer` in order for the changes to take effect.

#### 2. Editing Registry Key Values

- [Open the Registry Editor](https://www.top-password.com/blog/6-ways-to-open-registry-editor-in-windows-10/)
- Navigate to

> **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}**

- Click each subkey (with names such as 0000, 0001, etc.) to check the DriverDesc value that matches with your network card.
- Look for the registry entry NetworkAddress in the right pane, and change the value as your new MAC Address.
- If that entry doesn’t exist, right-click blank area to create a String value with the name NetworkAddress.
- Close Registery Editor
- Disable your network adapter and enable it again. The new Mac address will apply immediately.

Feel free to put in any other way to change MAC Address on Windows PC.