# How to change MAC Address in Windows OS using CLI/CMD?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, command-line

In Linux, I can change MAC Address easily using `ifconfig` command.

e.g.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Is possible to do the same via CLI in Windows OS?

I know we can change it via [Network Adapter's properties or registry](https://www.wikihow.com/Change-a-Computer%27s-Mac-Address-in-Windows), I just want to know if this is possible via CLI.

Comment: AFAIK I don't think there is any normal way to change your MAC address in Windows without using a GUI.

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1282823/814740) to know all workarounds to change MAC Address in windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the registry via CLI. Therefore, anything you can change via registry you can also change via CLI.

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\..." /v NetworkAddress /t REG_SZ /d 1a2b3c...
```